# DependencyCheck finds jenkins plugin cpe in a jar

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, dependencies

I'm trying to understand how does DependencyCheck (https://github.com/jeremylong/DependencyCheck, https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-check-maven/configuration.html) find cpe:

> Published Vulnerabilities CVE-2018-1000013  suppress
>
> Jenkins Release Plugin 2.9 and earlier did not require form
> submissions to be submitted via POST, resulting in a CSRF
> vulnerability allowing attackers to trigger release builds. CWE-352
> Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)

in a jar that was built using jenkins with release plugin. Jar itself has no dependencies related to jenkins.

Using maven or just cli gives the same result.

Jar in question is included in a parent project. Parent project's pom:

```
<groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
<artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
<version>${dependency-check-maven.version}</version>
<configuration>
    <skipProvidedScope>true</skipProvidedScope>
    <skipRuntimeScope>true</skipRuntimeScope>
    <nugetconfAnalyzerEnabled>false</nugetconfAnalyzerEnabled>
    <nuspecAnalyzerEnabled>false</nuspecAnalyzerEnabled>
    <assemblyAnalyzerEnabled>false</assemblyAnalyzerEnabled>
    <failBuildOnCVSS>0</failBuildOnCVSS>
    <suppressionFiles>
        <suppressionFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/dependency-check-suppressions.xml</suppressionFile>
    </suppressionFiles>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Does dependency-check project somehow find jenkins version from jar file and find vulnerabilities?

Comment: It's probably a false positive. Recommend submitting an [issue w/details](https://github.com/jeremylong/DependencyCheck/issues); tag as flase positive.

Comment: Thing is, jenkins itself has this issue. I just don't know how depdencycheck connects jar with it.

Comment: But you said "Using maven or just cli gives the same result", which assumed meant you ran outside of Jenkins, ie; just from the command line: `mvn org.owasp:dependency-check:check `.

Comment: Yes, I ran it using maven. But jar was built using jenkins environment (and jenkins lists theses problems as well). Which was weird was for me. I thought maybe there is jenkins ID or something in jar and dependency checker checks that? Though I can't find anything like that

Comment: So build it it independently from source, from command line with the owasp check. And if it reports same, then it's a 100% false.positive and file an issue. Can't explain how a Jenkins plugin could possibly end up in a jar it built. You can `jar tf your.jar` and see it won't have a jenkins plugin inside.

Comment: When I build the jar with maven, jenkins release issues are gone. That's why it does not look like false positive. though I have no idea how does dep checker know about if jar was build locally or with jenkins and downloaded.

Comment: It would seem, that having string "jenkins" in manifest file causes this.